# The application crash when i am trying to connect my app to php

Tags: android, json

I am trying to connect my project to a database on server but it crashes, there is no error in the application but it crashes when I run it on the mobile,  I already added the internet permission

```
   public class Chat extends ListActivity {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL="http://tourin.esy.es/php/historical.php";
        private static final String TAG_SITE_NAME = "Site_Name";
        private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
        private JSONArray mComments = null;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mCommentList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.historical_sites);
            //setListAdapter();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            new LoadSites().execute();
        }
        public class LoadSites extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
            @Override

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog= new ProgressDialog(Chat.this);
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Chat.this,mCommentList,R.layout.historical_sites_rows,
                        new String[]{TAG_SITE_NAME},new int[]{R.id.sitenam});
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
        public void updateJSONdata(){
            mCommentList =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            Json_Parsing jParser = new Json_Parsing();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);
            try {

                mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Site_Name = c.getString(TAG_SITE_NAME);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_SITE_NAME, Site_Name);
                    mCommentList.add(map);
                }
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.historical_sites_rows,mCommentList);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
```

this code for the Json parser

```
 public class Json_Parsing {
    static InputStream is = null;

    static JSONObject jObj = null;

    static String json = "";

            // constructor

    public Json_Parsing() {
           }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request

        try {

            // defaultHttpClient

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            is = httpEntity.getContent();



        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object

        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }


        return jObj;
    }

}     

        }
```

Comment: please post your error logcat?

Comment: there is no error  it is not working while it is in use